# Xtext: adding another problems category (besides warnings and errors)

Tags: validation, warnings, xtext

I want to add a third category on my DSL eclipse, so I can see errors, warnings and `myNewCat` seperately.
I also want to have a very similar (same parameters) function like `warning()` and `error()` so I can call `myNewCat()` from my validation classes.
What's the easiest way to do it?

Example what the outcome should look like
[image: Example what the outcome should look like]

Answer (score 1):

The Problems view groups issues using marker attributes, one of which is severity (i.e. error, warning, info), but there are other marker attributes you can group by, e.g. type. You can select the grouping in the Problems view from the View Menu (the white down arrow on the upper right of the Problems view) -> Group By -> ...

It is possible to use the `org.eclipse.ui.markerSupport` extension point to customize the available groupings (cf. [Marker Support Reference](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_ide_markerSupport.html)). I don't think adding an additional severity level to the "Severity" grouping will work because a fixed number of severity levels is hard-coded at several places, e.g. `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.Markers.getMarkerCounts(MarkerEntry[])`, but you can create your own grouping which may depend on the severity level and other additional criteria.

At this point, you may also want to think about whether the group you want to add really is another severity that goes in line with error, warning and info (e.g. minor warning, recommendation or similar) or whether you actually want a different kind of grouping. But let's assume you want another severity level as you asked.

To add a custom grouping based on a custom severity attribute, add the following extension to your UI project's `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.ide.markerSupport">
    <markerContentGeneratorExtension generatorId="org.eclipse.ui.ide.problemsGenerator" id="org.example.mydsl.problemGeneratorExtension">
        <markerGrouping id="org.example.mydsl.customSeverityGrouping" label="Custom severity">
             <markerGroupingEntry id="org.example.mydsl.errorSeverity" label="Errors" priority="30" />
             <markerGroupingEntry id="org.example.mydsl.warningSeverity" label="Warnings" priority="20" />
             <markerGroupingEntry id="org.example.mydsl.infoSeverity" label="Infos" priority="10" />
             <markerGroupingEntry id="org.example.mydsl.myAdditionalSeverity" label="My Additional severity" priority="5" />

             <markerAttributeGrouping attribute="customseverity" markerType="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
                <markerAttributeMapping markerGroupingEntry="org.example.mydsl.errorSeverity" value="2" />
                <markerAttributeMapping markerGroupingEntry="org.example.mydsl.warningSeverity" value="1" />
                <markerAttributeMapping markerGroupingEntry="org.example.mydsl.infoSeverity" value="0" />
                <markerAttributeMapping markerGroupingEntry="org.example.mydsl.myAdditionalSeverity" value="10" />
             </markerAttributeGrouping>
        </markerGrouping>
    </markerContentGeneratorExtension>
</extension>
```

The `markerGroupingEntry` elements define the categories: The three well-known categories and your additional severity level `org.example.mydsl.myAdditionalSeverity`. The `markerGroupingEntry` elements are used for filling these categories with issues according to the value of the marker attribute "customseverity". Your additional severity level is filled when the attribute "customseverity" has value 10.

Now you can open this grouping from "Problem View Menu -> Group By -> Custom severity"

After this, you have to make sure that the attribute value is actually set. I think the place to do this is `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.validation.MarkerCreator.setMarkerAttributes(Issue, IResource, IMarker)` so you have to create your own subclass `MydslMarkerCreator`:

```
package org.example.xsduse.ui.validation

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.validation.MarkerCreator
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Issue

class XsduseMarkerCreator extends MarkerCreator {
    public static val CUSTOM_SEVERITY = "customseverity"

    override protected setMarkerAttributes(Issue issue, IResource resource, IMarker marker) throws CoreException {
        super.setMarkerAttributes(issue, resource, marker)

        if (issue.code.startsWith("org.example.mydsl.customseverityissues.")) {
            marker.setAttribute(XsduseMarkerCreator.CUSTOM_SEVERITY, 10)
        } else {
            marker.setAttribute(XsduseMarkerCreator.CUSTOM_SEVERITY, marker.getAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY))
        }
    }
}
```

The standard severity levels severities are passed using `org.eclipse.xtext.diagnostics.Severity`, which is an enum so you can't extend it. So you can't use it to pass your additional severity level. As an example, I used the issue code to transport this information, using a common prefix for all issues of the additional severity level. For the other severity levels I re-used the original severity attribute, which is set in `super.setMarkerAttributes(...)`.

Don't forget to register the class in the UI module (`MydslUiModule`):

```
...

class MydslUiModule extends AbstractMydslUiModule {
    def Class<? extends MarkerCreator> bindMarkerCreator() {
        XsduseMarkerCreator
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you can use a validator as usual and issues with an issue code starting with "org.example.mydsl.customseverity." will be shown in your new category.

Creating functions like error(), warning() etc. didn't make sense in my example because I transported the information in the issue code, but if you decide for a different channel, you might want to actually implement them.